# Unable to find the template

Tags: templating, modules

I know this question has been asked multiple times. I have read all the post on this topic, and craft's docs. But still, I haven't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I would really appreciate a hand here!

I'm using Craft 3.7, and I am trying to render a template file, which is called from my module's twig extension.

I have this:

The template file is in

`modules/abc/passwordglobal/src/templates/_formTemplate.twig`

`In app.php:`

```
'modules' => [
        'password-global' => abc\passwordglobal\PasswordGlobal::class,
    ],
    'bootstrap' => ['password-global']
```

And in my *twig extension* file, I have a function with this code:

```
// ... returns html template;
$oldMode = \Craft::$app->view->getTemplateMode();
\Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_CP);
$html = \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('password-global/templates/_formTemplate');
\Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode($oldMode);

return $html;
```

And the error I see:

**Twig Template Loading Error – craft\web\twig\TemplateLoaderException**

**Unable to find the template “password-global/templates/_formTemplate”.**

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the template root (`password-global`) in your main module file. This is a gotcha when working on site-specific modules instead of plugins – plugins get a template root based on their ID automatically, but modules don't.

Use [View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-view.html#event-register-cp-template-roots) to define your template root:

```php
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\web\View;
use craft\events\RegisterTemplateRootsEvent;

// put this inside the init() method
Event::on(
    View::class,
    View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS,
    function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
        $e->roots[$this->id] = __DIR__ . '/src/templates';
    }
);
```

See [Template Roots](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/template-roots.html) for more information.

---

Small sidenote, you don't need to manually keep track of and restore the old template mode afterwards. If you pass a template mode as the third argument to `View::renderTemplate`, it only applies to this function call:

```php
return \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate(
    'password-global/_formTemplate',
    [],
    \craft\web\View::TEMPLATE_MODE_CP,
);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help with this. It clarifies quite a few things. I did as you indicated: added the template root in the main module's file init(). And in my twig extension file, in the function that should render the temlate I have now `\Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('password-global/_formTemplate');`
However, I still get the same error. Not sure what's wrong. 
Side question: I'm using this on the site's front end. Should I use `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS` instead?

Comment: @mauricio Yes, use EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS if you need the templates in the frontend. Otherwise they won't be available. Or just use both :)

Comment: @mauricio If it's still not working, try rendering the template with TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE. Not quite sure how custom template roots interact with template modes.

Comment: hmm, Ok, using now   EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, and rendering with TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE. Do you know if there's a way to see what is the root url that got registered in the  module's init()?

Comment: wow, finally, problem solved(!!)... 
By chance I saw another post using this registration of the template root:
```
Event::on(
            View::class, 
            View::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, 
            function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
            if (is_dir($baseDir = $this->getBasePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates')) {
                $e->roots[$this->id] = $baseDir;
                }
            }
        );
```
The little change in the init made the difference. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, this is what solved my issue:
On main class' init() function -- note the **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** part:

```
Event::on(
            View::class, 
            View::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, 
            function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
            if (is_dir($baseDir = $this->getBasePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates')) {
                $e->roots[$this->id] = $baseDir;
                }
            }
        );
```

This is registering this path:

```
/app/modules/abc/passwordglobal/src/templates
```

And in my twig extension function, there's no need to add the TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE parameter:

```
 $html = \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate(
                'password-global/_formTemplate');
```